# How to update the object values inside the object in angular

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
data = [{
    id: 'stud1',
    row: 1,
    currLine: {
        row: 1,
        line: 1
    },
    newLine: {
        row: 1,
        line: 1
    }
},{
    id: 'stud2',
    row: 2,
    currLine: {
        row: 2,
        line: 2
    },
    newLine: {
        row: 2,
        line: 2
    }
},{
    id: 'stud3',
    row: 3,
    currLine: {
        row: 3,
        line: 3
    },
    newLine: {
        row: 3,
        line: 3
    }
}]


newData = {
    row: 3,
    line: 3,
    data: { id: 'e1', name: 'edward' },
    section: { id: 's1', name: 'emerald' }
}
```

What I'm trying to do here is to update the newLine in the row3.

the output should be like this.

```
[{
    id: 'stud1',
    row: 1,
    currLine: {
        row: 1,
        line: 1
    },
    newLine: {
        row: 1,
        line: 1
    }
},{
    id: 'stud2',
    row: 2,
    currLine: {
        row: 2,
        line: 2
    },
    newLine: {
        row: 2,
        line: 2
    }
},{
    id: 'stud3',
    row: 3,
    currLine: {
        row: 3,
        line: 3
    },
    newLine: {
         row: 3,
         line: 3,
         data: { id: 'e1', name: 'edward' },
         section: { id: 's1', name: 'emerald' }
    }
}]
```

I tried to use the filter but it always error:

```
data.filter((x: any) => x['row'] === newData['row']);
data['newLine'] = DATA;
```

but it errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the expected out using `map`. Here is a working example:

```js
var data = [{ id: 'stud1', row: 1, currLine: { row: 1, line: 1 }, newLine: { row: 1, line: 1 }},{ id: 'stud2', row: 2, currLine: { row: 2, line: 2 }, newLine: { row: 2, line: 2 }},{ id: 'stud3', row: 3, currLine: { row: 3, line: 3 }, newLine: { row: 3, line: 3 }}];

var newData = { row: 3, line: 3, data: { id: 'e1', name: 'edward' }, section: { id: 's1', name: 'emerald' }};

const result = data.map(k=>k.row===newData.row ? (k.newLine=newData, k) : k);

console.log(result);
```

Inside map I'm putting ternary operator for matching the value, if matched we assign `newLine` property to `newData` else the current object is returned as is.

Comment: Cannot assign to read only property 'newLine' of object '[object Object]'

Comment: @BeginnerCoder You can create shallow copy of your array either with `spread operator` or `Object.assign` and then use `map`.

Answer (score 0):

If your `data` array has a constant number of elements, you should be able to do:

```js
data[2].data = newData.data;
data[2].section = newData.section;
```

If the array has a variable number of elements, you can do:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if (data[i].row === newData.row) {
    data[i].data = newData.data;
    data[i].section = newData.section;
  }
}
```

Judging by the code you wrote, it seems as though you thought the `filter` function would update the `data` variable in place with the item that matches the filter. That's not how `filter` works—it returns a new array of all the items that match your condition (in this case `x['row'] === newData['row']`).

So, when you run `data['newLine'] = DATA;`, you're assigning something to a property called `newLine` on the `data` array. That data array hasn't changed because `filter` did not mutate it.

Presumably your code errors because the variable `DATA` is not declared anywhere.